# Image asset not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: image, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

The situation is one where there is no issue in Development, but in Production ( with assets pre-compiled ) an image is not found in the asset pipeline.

I feel like I'm missing something subtle, but after reading documentation and searching on this site I cannot pin point the reason for the issue.

snippet from .html.erb view file:

```
<div class="media-left">
   <figure class="image is-256x256">
      <%= image_tag('95090365.jpeg') %>
   </figure>
 </div>
```

The precompiled image is in /public/assets :-

```
95090365-8976ee2cb59e500cd649fb288749282959ada00f93955c319300e4d85779d687.jpg
```

When I try to load the relevant view, I get a 500 error on the page, and see this in log/production.log :

```
I, [2020-03-16T05:11:48.841878 #1]  INFO -- : [d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]   Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2020-03-16T05:11:48.842593 #1]  INFO -- : [d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]   Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 406)
I, [2020-03-16T05:11:48.842735 #1]  INFO -- : [d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 1785)
F, [2020-03-16T05:11:48.843367 #1] FATAL -- : [d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]   
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "95090365.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]      7:       <article class="media">
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]      8:         <div class="media-left">
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]      9:           <figure class="image is-256x256">
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]     10:             <%= image_tag('95090365.jpeg') %>
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]     11:           </figure>
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]     12:         </div>
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]     13:         <div class="media-content">
[d802e301-bbe2-4881-83ba-8e107adaa04e]
```

I noticed on some other questions and answers, that people have set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

to fix this error, but I see in the Rails documentation that is isnt recommended for Production

> This mode uses more memory, performs more poorly than the default, and is not recommended" - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

I've tried the image_tag with the jpeg suffix and without, and same issue with both.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this image_tag('95090365.jpg')

Comment: Thanks!, yes, I noticed it just after I posted the question, and just got it working as you posted. I knew it would be something subtle, ( and silly ).

Answer (score 2):

```
 <%= image_tag('95090365.jpeg') %>
```

needed to change to

```
 <%= image_tag('95090365.jpg') %>
```